# While loop into a switch in PHP?

Tags: php, loops, while-loop, switch-statement, case

I am trying to make a website in different languages and I retrieve this information from a database. For now I have two languages in there: English and Dutch.

What I would like to do is getting all the language possibilities and put this into a switch. So if people will click on for example this link: index.php?page=NL they will get the Dutch translation of the page.

So this is the code that I am using. It works so far but it shows I think the language option and the default option. Because when I remove default I only get the code ones.

```
    <div id="content">
    <?php 
    //Retrieve languages
    $querySwitchLang = "SELECT * FROM languages";
    $resultSwitchLang = mysql_query($querySwitchLang);
    ?>
    <?php
    while($rowSwitchLang = mysql_fetch_array($resultSwitchLang)){
        switch($page){
            case $rowSwitchLang['langCode']:include('page.php');break;
            default: include('pageDefault.php'); 
            break;
        }
    }
    ?>   
    </div>
```

So actually I wanted to have it like this because now it runs the switch statements as many times as there are languages I think:

```
    <div id="content">
    <?php 
    //Retrieve languages
    $querySwitchLang = "SELECT * FROM languages";
    $resultSwitchLang = mysql_query($querySwitchLang);
    ?>
    <?php
    include('functions.php');

        switch($page){
                        while($rowSwitchLang = mysql_fetch_array($resultSwitchLang)){
            case $rowSwitchLang['langCode']:include('page.php');break;
                        }
            default: include('pageDefault.php'); 
            break;

    }
    ?>   
    </div>
```

But this doesn't work because then I will get this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'while' (T_WHILE), expecting case (T_CASE) or default (T_DEFAULT) or '}' in C:\wamp\www\glimpler\index.php on line 6
```

I can't realy figure out how to solve this problem.

Comment: Not possible. One work around would be to put your loop in a function and then call that for your case.

Comment: why do you need a loop for every language when you're including the same page every time anyway?

Comment: Any reason for not using `WHERE` to check this inside your SQL query?

Comment: Surely if else would be better suited here? The main argument for using switch over if/else is the code is neater and less of it. You've lost that using whiles and whatnot with switch, so might as well use if/elseif/else and take advantage of it's more appropriate structure for this sort of scenario.

Comment: Also, `mysql_` functions are deprecated as of PHP 5.5 and will be removed in the future. I suggest you to use PDO or MySQLi instead.

Comment: Do you have different page (page.php) for each language, like: page_nl.php, page_de.php, page_en.php etc?

Comment: [gettext](http://php.net/manual/en/book.gettext.php) exists for a reason..

Answer (score 0):

i think you're approach is a bit messy is to use file for the translation instead of db, like this:

NL.php

```
   <?php
      return [
         'welcome' =>'welkom',
         'goodbye' =>'afscheid'
         ];
```

then in your index

```
$translationFile =$_GET['page'].'.php';
if(file_exists(translationFile)){
    $language = include(translationFile);
}
else{
 die("Couldn't find translation file. Page Terminated!");
}
```

and then just echo your translation.

```
echo $language['welcome'] . ' USER';
```

the advantage is not havinge multiple page for every language and that make it easier to update.
reguarding the default you can just set $_GET['page'] to 'EN' if is not set.